# Error code: 1364 Field doesnt have a default value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database in which there exist two tables ***campaign_details*** and ***product_details***.

**campaign_details**

[image: campaign_details_columns]

**product_details**

[image: product_details_columns]

The column ***pr_name*** in **campaign_details** references ***pr_name*** in **product_details**.

Due to the vast size of the **campaign_details** table I decided to make a smaller table named **campaign_info** to increase speed of data access.

**campaign_info**

[image: campaign_info_columns]

Here ***cmp_name*** corresponds to ***cmp_name*** in **campaign_details** and ***pr_id*** corresponds to ***pr_id*** of the associated ***pr_name*** in **product_details**.

Hence now I want to remove the columns ***cmp_name*** and ***pr_name*** from **campaign_details** and add a new column ***cmp_info_id***

[image: new_campaign_details_columns]

I am using this query to add the values to ***cmp_info_id***

```
Insert into nredb.campaign_details(cmp_info_id) (Select ci.cmp_info_id from nredb.campaign_info ci, nredb.campaign_details cd,nredb.product_details pd 
where ci.cmp_name=cd.cmp_name and ci.pr_id in (select pd1.pr_id from nredb.product_details pd1,nredb.campaign_details cd1 where cd1.pr_name=pd1.pr_name));
```

But it gives this error ***Error Code: 1364. Field 'pr_name' doesn't have a default value***

Any help with what could be going wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to insert into your `campaign_details` table, but you're not specifying a value for `pr_name` in your query, because that's not being picked up by the nested `Select` query.

You have two options:

1. Modify your `Select` query so that it also returns a `pr_name`;
2. Set a default value for `pr_name` on your `campaign_details` table so that it still gets populated with something if you don't specify a value in the `Insert` query.

It is also possible that you're not trying to add a new row to the table at all, but trying to modify the `cmp_info_id` field of an existing row. If that's the case, then you don't want an `Insert` query, you want an `Update`:

```
UPDATE nredb.campaign_details SET cmp_info_id=(SELECT ...) WHERE <condition to select row to update>
```

Comment: Worked nicely with an UPDATE